# Полнотекстовий поиск по любому вхождению в строку от 3х символов

Tags: mysql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Друзья, В таблице есть колонка name.
В таблице есть запись, к примеру "Иванов Роман Капранович"

Задача создать такой запрос, который смог бы вывести данную строку "Иванов Роман Капранович" если искомая фраза, к примеру всего 4 символа - "иван". В данный момент я все тестирую с запросом в таком формате:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('".$_GET['user']."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Но как показала практика этот запрос не находит того что мне нужно. Он работает только в том случае, если искомая фраза полностью написана, без ошибок и целиком (слава богу что не реагирует на регистр). Но моя задача сделать поиск с "полуслова"

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(name) like '%иван%'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Вот будет правильный формат запроса для поиска любого вхождения строки:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('*".$_GET['user']."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: `curl "http://somewhere/index.php?user='); DROP TABLE users; --"` - и сарзу пример SQL-инъекции

Comment: ребята вставлял чужой код. понятно что все данные обрабатываются я заострял внимание не на это, чисто на поиск) никто так не пишет:)

Answer (score 1):

'*".$_GET['user']."*'
О боже мой, [`SQL Injection`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) в чистом виде!

**Никогда не подставляете необработанные данные из реквеста в БД!!!**

Целые данные обрабатываются `(int)$_GET['id']`, деситичные `(float)$_GET['price']`, строки, в идеале [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), или на худой конец [addslashes](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.addslashes.php) `addslashes($_GET['string'])` и обязательно вставка должна быть в одинарных кавычках. Чтобы заэкранировать кавычку в запросе, нужно поставить перед ней бэкслэш `\`.

```
'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST (\'*'.addslashes($_GET['user']).'*\' IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
```

Но вы используете не оптимальный запрос. Это делается проще и быстрее через `LIKE`, при условии, что у вас ваша таблица или поле `user` создавалось с атрибутом `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`, то есть регистронезависимый юникод.

```
'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE \'%'.addslashes($_GET['user']).'%\'';
```